# Is this selection by Regex Coach is incorrect?

Tags: regex, pcre

`[^a]` is as interpreted as follows:

[image]
You can see it's selecting only first character which is not `a`. 
But [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) selects this differently as shown in following screen shot.

[image]

[Regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) makes sure that `[^a]` matches every character which is not `a`.
So which one of these is erroneous?

Comment: Note the checkboxes in the regex coach, check the "g" for global match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^a]` stands for "any character different than 'a'".

In your second example, you've added the `g` modifier, which makes that selection `global` and not only the first occurrence.

Make the same selection in both applications and you should have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

Notice how in the first screenshot the `g` flag is unselected? It only matches the first non-a character (with a yellow background).

The second screenshot shows the expression `/[^a]/g` which means "as many non-a characters as are matchable" (hits have a blue background).